# RandomForest with Weka in Java

Tags: java, weka

I am working on a project and I need some examples how to implement RandomForest in Java with weka? I did it with [IBk()](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/index.html?weka/classifiers/lazy/IBk.html), it worked. If I do it with [RandomForest](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/index.html?weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.html) in the same way, it does not work. 
Does anyone have a simple example for me how to implement RandomForest and how to get probability for each class (i did it with IBk with`classifier.distributionForInstance(instance)` Function and it returned me probabilities for each class). How can I do it for RandomForest? I will need to get probability of every tree and to combine it?

```
//example

ConverrterUtils.DataSource source = new ConverterUtils.DataSource ("..../edit.arff); 
Instances dataset = source.getDataSet();
dataset.setClassIndex(dataset.numAttributes() - 1); 
IBk classifier = new IBk(5); classifier.buildClassifier(dataset);

Instance instance = new SparseInstance(2); 
instance.setValue(0, 65)   //example data 
instance.setValue(1, 120);   //example data 
double[] prediction = classifier.distributionForInstance(instance);

//now I get the probability for the first class   
System.out.println("Prediction for the first class is: "+prediction[0]);
```

Comment: Can you show some minimal working example of what you've tried with `IBk`, where it worked, so we can understand what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just added working example as a new answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the the **infogain** while buidling the Model in the RandomForest. It is much slower and requires alot of memory while buidling model. I am not so sure about the documentation. you can add options or setValues while buiilding the model.

```
    //numFolds in number of crossvalidations usually between 1-10

    //br is your bufferReader
    Instances trainData = new Instances(br);
    trainData.setClassIndex(trainData.numAttributes() - 1);

    RandomForest rf = new RandomForest();
    rf.setNumTrees(50);

    //You can set the options here
    String[] options = new String[2];
    options[0] = "-R";                
    rf.setOptions(options);

    rf.buildClassifier(trainData);


    weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection as = new  weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection();
    Ranker ranker = new Ranker();



    InfoGainAttributeEval infoGainAttrEval = new InfoGainAttributeEval();
    as.setEvaluator(infoGainAttrEval);
    as.setSearch(ranker);
    as.setInputFormat(trainData);
    trainData = Filter.useFilter(trainData, as);

    Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation(trainData);
    evaluation.crossValidateModel(rf, trainData, numFolds, new Random(1));


    // Using HashMap to store the infogain values of the attributes 
    int count = 0;
    Map<String, Double> infogainscores = new HashMap<String, Double>();

    for (int i = 0; i < trainData.numAttributes(); i++) {
        String t_attr = trainData.attribute(i).name();
        //System.out.println(i+trainData.attribute(i).name());
        double infogain  = infoGainAttrEval.evaluateAttribute(i);
        if(infogain != 0){
                //System.out.println(t_attr +  "= "+ infogain); 
                infogainscores.put(t_attr, infogain);
                count = count+1;
       }
    }

    //iterating over the hashmap

    Iterator it = infogainscores.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
       Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
       System.out.println(pair.getKey()+"  =  "+pair.getValue());
       System.out.println(pair.getKey()+"  =  "+pair.getValue());
       it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
```

Comment: What does 'InfoGainAttributeEval' do? Where in your example do you get results from the trees?

Comment: **InfoGainAttributeEval**  will Evaluates the worth of an attribute by measuring the information gain with respect to the class. I applied the filter on the trainData  `trainData = Filter.useFilter(trainData, as)` and then store in the Evaluation which is calculated in for loop and added to HashMap. Do accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: @Maxi how can I print the tree in java